# Running batch file to fetch code changes from Rational Team Concert

Tags: batch-file, rational-team-concert

My script simply logs in `RTC`, and then accept change sets so my local repository is update to date and ready for build.

```
lscm login ... (the rest omitted)
lscm accept ... (the rest omitted)
lscm logout ... (the rest omitted)
```

These commands are working fine if I run them one by one in a command shell.

However, if I save them in a .bat and run them in a batch, the execution stops after the first command (login) is completed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [an answer](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/152568/running-batch-script-with-two-lscm-commands-causes-finishing-script-just-after-finishing-first-command) to this question after half an hour of googling, hoping that this can help someone having the same problem.

> On Windows lscm itself is a batch command. To call it in a batch file, you may need to use:

```
call lscm login ... 
call lscm accept ...
call lscm logout ...
```